# How does JNIEnv global referencing differ from jobject in C?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have my JNI environment and jobject objects saved locally as of now. I found that for my JNI to run of ICS and up devices, I need to fix my JNI code. This is the error I get:

```
02-20 10:20:59.523: E/dalvikvm(21629): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x38100019
02-20 10:20:59.523: E/dalvikvm(21629): VM aborting
02-20 10:20:59.523: A/libc(21629): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 21629
```

I am confused about how to create/destroy these globals, and if I am even doing it right.

My application currently runs fine on all pre-ICS devices using this code:

```
BYTE Java_my_eti_commander_RelayAPIModel_00024NativeCalls_InitRelayJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj  ) {

    myEnv = (env);
    myObject = obj;

    changeID = (*myEnv)->GetStaticMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "changeItJavaWrapper", "(S)V"  );
    getID    = (*myEnv)->GetStaticMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "getItJavaWrapper"   , "(S)S"   );
    putID    = (*myEnv)->GetStaticMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "putItJavaWrapper"   , "(B)V" );
    flushID  = (*myEnv)->GetStaticMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "flushItJavaWrapper" , "()V"   );
    delayID  = (*myEnv)->GetStaticMethodID( myEnv, myObject, "delayItJavaWrapper" , "(S)V"  );

    RelayAPI_SetBaud= WrapSetBaud;
    RelayAPI_get    = WrapGetIt;
    RelayAPI_put    = WrapPutIt;
    RelayAPI_flush  = WrapFlushIt;
    RelayAPI_delay  = WrapDelayIt;
    ...
}
```

Under the `GetStaticMethodID` calls, the RelayAPI_ variables are all function pointers that lead here:

```
void WrapSetBaud( WORD w ) {
    return (*myEnv)->CallStaticVoidMethod( myEnv, myObject, changeID, w );
}

short WrapGetIt( WORD time ) {
    return (*myEnv)->CallStaticShortMethod( myEnv, myObject, getID, time );
}

void WrapPutIt( BYTE buff ) {
    return (*myEnv)->CallStaticVoidMethod( myEnv, myObject, putID, buff );
}

void WrapFlushIt( void ) {
    return (*myEnv)->CallStaticVoidMethod( myEnv, myObject, flushID );
}

void WrapDelayIt( WORD wait ) {
    return (*myEnv)->CallStaticVoidMethod( myEnv, myObject, delayID, wait );
}
```

Finally, it returns to my Java code here:

```
public static void changeItJavaWrapper( short l ) throws IOException {
    mModelService.changeitJava( l );
}

public static void flushItJavaWrapper() {
    mModelService.flushitJava();
}

public static void putItJavaWrapper( byte p ) {
    mModelService.putitJava( p );
}

public static void delayItJavaWrapper( short wait ) {
   mModelService.delayitJava( wait );
}

public static short getItJavaWrapper( short s ) throws IOException {
    return mModelService.getitJava( s );
}
```

I have changed my initializations to:

```
myEnv = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
myObject = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
```

But i'm extremely confused with this, as they have the same parameters, and it just doesn't make sense. I can't find documentation for this method anywhere as stupid as that sounds, [`this tutorial`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html), [`this page`](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html), and [`the oracle docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242) don't have any information on the `NewGlobalRef` method itself.

**EDIT**

```
jmethodID changeID;
jmethodID getID;
jmethodID putID;
jmethodID flushID;
jmethodID delayID;
jobject myObject;
jclass    bluetoothClass;
JNIEnv *myEnv;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: `myEnv = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);` is just wrong. [You mustn't cache this value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202621/how-to-create-static-jni-environment-pointer).

What you're allowed to is to cache method IDs, field IDs, class references, ... (but make sure you clean up this stuff afterwards). But caching these values requires special measures.

**Why?** The problem is that the JVM is allowed to load and unload classes according to the needs of the program. Therefore it could happen that a class is unloaded as soon as the last instance of the class has been destroyed by the garbage collector. As soon as this happens your cached IDs are not valid anymore. It's possible that the IDs will be the same after the JVM loads the class again but this is not guaranteed.

**Solution:** If you want to cache these IDs you have to tell the JVM that it's not allowed to unload a class. This is exactly what `NewGlobalRef` does. You just increment the reference for the reference passed to `NewGlobalRef` so the reference count never drops to zero and grabage collection is not allowed to clean up the referenced element.

**Attention:** Creating a `NewGlobalRef` has a serious drawback: Other than in Java you have to make sure that you call `DeleteGlobalRef` if you don't need this reference anymore in order to reenable the garbage collection of the reference. (As the garbage collecter is not aware of wether you still need this reference or not) Or in other words: You have to make sure that you cleanup your garbage yourself otherwise you'll leave a memory leak.

I'd also say it's not a good idea to create a global ref for an object (unless you really want to keep the object alive) as this means the object won't ever get into garbage and therefore never will be freed.

**Better Variant:** If you want to cache these IDs in order to speedup access to a certain object, keep a global reference for the class (using `FindClass`) and grab the IDs from the class object `FindClass` returns.

Here's a (incomplete) example of what I mean. I usually create a structure holding all the IDs I need to access a class just to keep my namespaces clean. You can imagine this as follows:

```
/*! \brief Holds cached field IDs for MyClass.java */
typedef struct MyClass {
    int loaded;   /*!< Nonzero if the information are valid */

    jclass clazz;    /*!< Holds a global ref for the class */
    jfieldID aField; /*!< Holds the field ID of aField */
}tMyClass;

static tMyClass me = { 0 };
```

The easiest way is to provide a "connect" function for your object which does the initialization of the structure defined above.

```
/*! \brief This function fetches field IDs for a specific class in order to have
           faster access elsewhere in the code 

    \param env  a valid JNI environment 

    \return
            -  0 if OK
            - <0 if an error occured */
int MyClass_connect(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jobject theClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
    if (theClass == NULL) goto no_class;

    me.clazz = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(theClass);    // make it global to avoid class unloading and therefore
                                                    // invalidating the references obtained.
    if (me.clazz == NULL) goto no_memory;

      me.aField = env->GetFieldID(me.clazz, "aField", "I")    ;
    if (me.aField == NULL) goto no_aField;

    me.loaded = 1;
    return 0;

no_aField:
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(me.clazz);
no_memory:
no_class:
    return -1;
}
```

After calling `MyClass_connect` successfully you can use `me.aField` to shorten the code to access a the field in your code. Of course you have to provide a disconnect function which is called when MyClass is not required anymore:

```
void MyClass_disconnect(JNIEnv *env)
{
    if (me.loaded == 0) return;

    env->DeleteGlobalRef(me.clazz);
    memset(me, 0, sizeof(tMyClass));
}
```

Sorry for this a bit lengthy posting but I hope this helps to solve your confusion a bit and gives you a bit an insight of the inner workings of JNI together with a little receipe how to deal with this efficiently.

**Edit:** You can find documentation about JNI calls on [oracle's website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for this. do you happen to know any good websites that have any more information on this in C?

Comment: You are looking for information on what exactly? JNI? Best practice?

Comment: I am still a little lost, since I am using `GetStaticMethodID` instead of `GetFieldID`. For me to call the method I find later on in my code, I must also have the JNI Env saved globally, shown in my second code block. -- I also do not know what your tUsb_Device variable is, what does the number for that parameter compare to?

Comment: @JuiCe The tUsb_Device type is a copy-paste error. I took the code from a project I am working on. I corrected that. Sorry. Regarding the `Get*ID` functions it's basicly all the same. All of them retrieve specific attributes of a class or an object. `GetStaticMethodID` for example returns the ID of a static method of the class while `GetFieldID` gives an ID of a field in the class etc. I included a link to the JNI documentation in my posting. You find there all the information you need. Regarding JNIEnv you **mustn't** save that poiner. Why do you think you have to?

Comment: Only because I had done it in my second code block using the `CallStatic*Method`. I can't find any examples of the `CallStatic*Method` that don't use the JNI environment as a parameter. [`The docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4796) show the environment there. I am also not very familiar with C so if I am missing something obvious I'm sorry.

Comment: @JuiCe No need to excuse. Maybe I don't understand your application good enough. Who (which thread running in which environment) initiates the call of the "Wrap*" functions? It's crucial that the thread that makes JNI calls is attached to the JVM and has it's own JNIEnv (because this is thread specific).

Comment: the "Wrap*" functions are called all throughout my C code. The C code is an existing library which was previously used for Palm Pilots. Setit/Getit/Putit/Flushit/delayit used to point to the Palm pilot's bluetooth thread, but now all lead back to the Java end's bluetooth thread. If I'm not clear enough let me know. The way I have my code now it works which is what baffles me. I am editing my question with how I declare the variables at the top of the `.c` file.