# C code needs to call Java code buffer but no way to get its JNIEnv

Tags: java, android, c, jvm-crash, jnienv

I have a java buffer on which I need some c data manipulation. 
To do that I call a native function "SimpleFunction", which is calling  java code to retrive the buffer value at a specific index (buffer_read_byte) and to save the modified value (buffer_byte_write).

**Java side**:

```
byte buffer = new byte[100];
public static byte getByte(int index) {
    return buffer[index];
}   
public static void writeByte(int in, int index) {
    buffer[index] = (byte)(in);
}
private native void SimpleFunction(int size);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    setBufferModByteInt(0x55,i);
SimpleFunction(100);
```

**C side**:

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "algorithms/global.h"
#define LOG_TAG "NDK"
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
static JavaVM* jvm;

void Java_com_App_SimpleFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint size)
{
    int address=0;
    for(address=0;address<(int)(size);address++)
    {
        /*
        some data manipulation on ""value""
        */

        value=buffer_read_byte(env,this,address)&0xFF;
        buffer_byte_write(env,this,address,value);
    }
    return;
}

uint8_t buffer_read_byte(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint pos)
{
    uint8_t value=0;
    const char * ss="2";
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
     return;
    }

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/App/Class");
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
        return 0;
    }
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "getByte", "(I)B");
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
     return 0;
    }
    jbyte result = (*env)->CallStaticByteMethod(env, cls, method,pos);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
     return 0;
    }
    value=(uint8_t) result&0xFF;
    if(cls!=NULL)
    {
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,cls);
        if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
         return 0;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
void buffer_byte_write(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint pos, jint data)
{
    int value=data&0xFF;
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/App/Class");
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
        return;
    }
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "writeByte", "(II)V");
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
     return;
    }
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, method,value,pos);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
     return;
    }
    if(cls!=NULL)
    {
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,cls);
        if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
         return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The code above works.

Now let's suppose that the data manipulation is get by a lot of inner functions which at the kernel is using the c functions buffer_read_byte and buffer_byte_write.
How can I avoid at each call function level to explicitly pass as input **(JNIEnv * env, jobject this)**?

I have a lot of pre-existing functions  which at the end needs to access the java buffer with buffer_read_byte and buffer_byte_write.
How can I avoid in each pre-existing parent and child function to have to declared inputs **(JNIEnv * env, jobject this)**, since JNIEnv is required only in the kernel functions buffer_read_byte and buffer_byte_write?

I checked for global JVM:

```
void Java_com_App_SimpleFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint size)
{
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);
    int address=0;
    for(address=0;address<(int)(size);address++)
    {
        value=buffer_read_byte(address)&0xFF;
        /*
        some data manipulation on ""value""
        */
        buffer_byte_write(address,value);
    }
    return;
}
uint8_t buffer_read_byte(jint pos)
{
    JNIEnv * env;
    jint rs=(*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
    args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
    args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
    jint rs=(*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);

    //...

    return value;
}
uint8_t buffer_byte_write(jint pos, jint data)
{
    JNIEnv * env;
    jint rs=(*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
    args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
    args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
    jint rs=(*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);

    //...

    return;
}
```

But the call SimpleFunction(100) is not executing (I have no data modification on buffer) and makes app crash when try to execute **GetEnv** or, as well, **AttachCurrentThread**.

What is the best way for C code, that has no way to get its JNIenv, to call JAVA code?

Comment: _What is the best way for C code, that has no way to get its JNIenv, to call JAVA code?_ Give it a way to get the env. If you cannot do that for some strange reason the you need to write a proxy function that can access it, copies in data the real function will need, calls the real function, then copies back data as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need find out why it is crashing. Looks you are using correct method. Also you can check answers in questions below.

[How to create static JNI Environment Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202621/how-to-create-static-jni-environment-pointer)

[How to obtain JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) for asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900695/how-to-obtain-jni-interface-pointer-jnienv-for-asynchronous-calls)